# Cannot open database "playVideo" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE'

Tags: asp.net, iis

I am receiving the following error on my desktop while hosting a website in IIS7.0

> Cannot open database "playVideo" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE'

I have a SQL Server 2008 R2 installed and a database named "playVideo".

The problem is when I click browse on my website in IIS, it shows up the above errors please help.

Things I have done:

- Give db_owner rights to NTAUTHORITY\SYSTEM account in ssms
- My Website folder physical path's permission has been set to everyone -full control
- The application pool identity is LocalSystem
- Both SQL (Express) & SQL(MSSQL) service has started

Can someone help me out? I've searched the internet a lot but none works. All website, database files runs smoothly on my other laptop previously.

Comment: I've found the problem, its in the connection string locate in iis all i have to do is change the server name instead of "localhost" to "YourComputerName\YourSQLServerName" and the rest remain unchage thats all.